# Alternative flowers

Tags: compatibility

I'm compiling a list of elements that are compatible with the [Plant Flower Stem](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3741). In addition to the [Plant Flower Small](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3742), I'm aware of at least two alternatives —

- [Friends Accessories Star with Stud Holder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=11609)
- [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (4 Knobs)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=33291)

Are there any others?

Answer (score 4):

The LEGO Scala flowers and butterflies also fit. You can see them on this page: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=102

Also the LEGO Belville, flower, butterfly (same as Scala) and ladybug. You can see those here: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=48

And from LEGO Friends all the other flowers with hole in the middle fit as well: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=771